# Angular 14 standalone component to use singleton service instance

Tags: angular, typescript

Using the `APP_INITIALIZER` token in my app.module.ts to run initialization logic in one of my services works just fine, until I'm trying to use the same service in one of my standalone components, where I'm getting a new instance of the same service, but without the initialization.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [],
declarations: [],
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (fooService: FooService) => () => fooService.init(),
        deps: [FooService],
        multi: true,
    },
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    providers: [FooService],
})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService
    ) {}
}
```

When the component.ts being created, I'm getting a totally new instance of `fooService` and I have no way to run the `async init()` method before it happens.

Comment: You added `FooService` in providers array of `BarComponent`, this will create a new instance for each BarComponent, remove it from there and see if it works.

Comment: if you use compnent in routing, just do service init in resolver

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, can you share your strategy for it.

Comment: @lego No, unfortunately I had to find a completely differed approach to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you mark a service as a provider, an instance of it will be created. In your case the simplest approach would be to mark the service as application-wide using `{provideIn: 'root'}`. For example;

From docs [Singleton services](https://angular.dev/guide/ngmodules/singleton-services)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

But above is for NgModule based components and apps OR for app-wide services (loaders, auth, etc). This is app-wide which might not be very helpful if you have standalone sub-features. If you wanted to use a singleton across a standalone component and its components used within that; try below

From docs [At the Component level](https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection)

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'hero-list',
  template: '...',
  providers: [HeroService]
})
class HeroListComponent {}
```

In this case, be sure not to include the service in child components' provider list and only include in constructor. That way the same instance of the service will be reused.